# Struggling to solve system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Note: This is not homework. This is a problem I'm trying to figure out.

Let $i\in \{1,2,3\}$, and $W_i, X_i, T \in\mathbb R^+$ with $\sum_{i=1}^3 W_i = T$.

You know the values of all of the $X_i$ (i.e., $X_1, X_2$  and $X_3$ )  and you know the value of $T$.

The relation below has to hold: 
$$\tag{1}  W_1X_1 = W_2X_2 = W_2 + W_3X_3.$$

How do you find the values  of $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$?

**My confusion**

Normally, where:
$$\tag{2} W_1X_1 = W_2X_2 = W_3X_3$$ has to hold instead of $(1)$

I would use the equations written below to find the $W_i$
\begin{align}
W_1 &=  T/ (1 + [X_1/X_2 + X_1/X_3] )\\ \ \\
\tag{A} W_2 &= T/(1 + [X_2/X_3 + X_2/X_1])\\ \ \\
W_3 &= T/(1 + [X_3/X_2 + X_3/X_1])
\end{align}
And $(2)$ Would be true.

But I don't know how to find the $W_i$ given $(1)$

What I've considered is subtracting the added $W_2$ in the expression $W_2 + W_3X_3$ so that it would be $W_3X_3$ as in $(2)$ and spreading it out across  $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ in proportional amounts after having already worked out what they - the $W_i$ - are (using $(A)$ ), so that all the $W_iX_i$ are equal. Though in this case it'd be $(W_i + h)X_i$, where $h$ is an arbitrary variable with different values depending on the values of the $W_i$.

But this approach is crude, and I feel there are better ways to do this which  I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you write $Z=W_1X_1 = W_2X_2 = W_2 + W_3X_3$, you get a linear system of four equations in four unknowns:
\begin{align}
X_1W_1-Z&=0\\
X_2W_2-Z&=0\\
W_2+X_3W_3-Z&=0\\
W_1+W_2+W_3&=T
\end{align}
This corresponds to the augmented matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1&0&0&-1&0\\
0&X_2&0&-1&0\\
0&1&X_3&-1&0\\
1&1&1&0&T
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If you now perform row reduction, you get 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&\frac{TX_2X_3}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\
0&1&0&0&\frac{TX_1X_3}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\
0&0&1&0&\frac{TX_1(X_2-1)}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\
0&0&0&1&\frac{TX_1X_2X_3}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
That is, 
\begin{align}
W_1&=\frac{TX_2X_3}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\ \ \\
W_2&=\frac{TX_1X_3}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\ \ \\
W_3&=\frac{TX_1(X_2-1)}{X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_2X_3-X_1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Great help, thanks.